# An analysis qual problem

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I am not really sure how to solve the following problem:  It is a qual problem.  I was thinking of invoking some sort of chang of variables and then holders but not sure it I can.

Find all $q ≥ 1,$ such that $f(x^2) ∈ L^q((0, 1))$ for any $f(x) ∈ L^4((0, 1)).$

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What is $m$? This could play a rôle.

Comment: It's just the normal measure on $R$

Comment: I edited out the measure, it is obvious from the context what it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said, the way to solve this proceeds by applying the change of variables $x \mapsto \sqrt{x}$. You can use the change of variables theorem (see Rudin's Real and Complex Analysis, theorem 7.26) since $(0,1)$ is open, $x \mapsto \sqrt{x}$ is continuous in $(0,1)$, $\sqrt{(0,1)} = (0,1)$ is measurable and $x \mapsto \sqrt{x}$ is one-to-one and differentiable.

If you do this change of variables and then Holder's inequality you see that $q$ should be less than $4$ (if you want to use Holder's inequality). To see whether $q = 4$ is achievable you should recall when is Holder's inequality an equality and try to find an explicit example.